# Qt Creator Auto-completion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, autocomplete, qt-creator

I've been using QtCreator on Windows for a few days now, and I plan to use it as my main IDE to code in C++ (I won't use Qt's library for now).

Though, I really miss Visual studio's auto completion, especially when typing a function.

I've tried to use Clang Code Model, but it doesn't seem to solve *my "issues"*, which are :

**1. Qt's auto-completion isn't as reactive as Visual Studio's ;**

**2. If one starts to type a function and its first argument before the argument list shows up, one has to delete the opening parenthese and wait a little before it eventually appears ;**

**3. The argument list and the auto-complete box can't be shown at the same time ;**

**4. You usually have to enable manually the auto-completion by pression ctrl + space.**

Comment: Does your computer have enough RAM and a decent graphics card?  It might be that if these are running low, that Qt Creator's threads may slow down... possibly...

Comment: Well, Qt's auto completion is reactive enough most of the time, yet it isn't as _instant_ as visual studio's. I won't complain much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used both Qt Creator and Visual Studio quite a bit.  IMHO, they are both comparable.  The Ctrl+Space works fine for me... I almost never hover with the mouse to trigger information about a function.  I think there is a similar shortcut key in Visual Studio.  The integration with the Qt Libraries and signals and slots and the designer, makes Qt Creator awesome.  I haven't felt like Qt Creator was slow or fast compared to Visual Studio.

I like the default shortcut keys in Qt better than the VS defaults, so I ended up remapping most of the shortcut keys in Visual Studio having to do with build, run, indent, and comment.

All the options related to the auto completion can be found under:

```
Qt Creator > Preferences (mac) > Text Editor > Completion
```

or

```
Qt Creator > Tools > Options > Text Editor > Completion
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54888-QtCreator-slow

It looks like it might be tied to too many `.pro.user` files in the folder.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/39712/solved-slow-or-not-working-auto-completion-in-qtcreator-3-0-1-running-on-linux-mint-64bit-cinnamon/4

https://www.google.com/search?q=speed%20up%20qt%20creator%20auto%20complete

Hope that helps.

PS - The Qt Libraries, its documentation and the community around it are awesome and worth looking into.

Comment: I'm using CMake to build my projects, and I don't think it's related to these. I'll check out your links anyway, I'll probably find something useful. Thank you

Comment: Good luck... Hopefully you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help > About plugins, uncheck ClangCodeModel. Will activate code completion and project view outline.

My Qt version

`Qt Creator 4.11.1 (Based on Qt 5.14.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit))`

[image: Disable ClangCodeModel]

Comment: This solved my problem. Having ClangCodeModel checked increases my autocomplete time for a 100ms to over 1 second.

Comment: @LukeDupin "You can set a timeout in milliseconds for code completion in the Timeout in ms field." from Tools > Options > Text Editor > Completion.

Comment: My completion timeout was set to 400 ms, but the timeout with ClangCodeModel was definitely slower (several seconds).