# Qt Creator cannot Auto-Complete Standard C++

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qt-creator

Today I met a question. When I use `std::map` in my Qt project, I found Qt Creator can not auto-compelete functions.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

......
    using mymap = map<string, vector<string> >;
    mymap m;
    for(mymap::iterator it=m.begin();
        it!=m.end(); it++){
        string item = it->first;
    }
......
```

In this code block, the `->first` is code by myself. When I code `it` complete, Qt Creator cannot show all functions even `->`. How to solve the problem? Can you help me?

I use Qt5.7.0 with Mingw5.3.0, and my Qt Creator version is 4.11.0.

Comment: You could try [clang code model](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html). Worked quite fine for me so far, except it becomes slow with bigger/ complex projects. Although, I don't know how it behaves on Windows...

Comment: I load clang code model plugin and it can auto-complete code, but it is so slowly to auto-complete. I don't know if it is because of the reason in the windows environment. Thank you very  much. I will try more ways.

Comment: I also found difference between don't use ```using``` and  after use ```using```. For example, ```using myv = vector<pair<string, string> >;  myv::iterator it1 = vec.begin();```, ```it1``` cannot auto-complete. If code like this ```vector<pair<string, string> >::iterator it1;``` it can auto-complete.

Comment: possible duplication? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899334/qt-creator-auto-completion

Comment: It has some differents. I code with Qt's functions can auto-compele, but when I use standard c++ like `map<int, int>::iterator it;` with `it`'s functions cannot auto-compele. I really don't know how to solve it until now.