# Qt Creator Can not Auto-Complete Standard C++ without Plugin ClangCodeModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I use Qt5.14.2 and my QtCreator's version is 10.0.2. My pc OS is Debian.
When I enable the plugin ClangCodeModel it can auto-complete code but it is so slowly. Without the plugin ClangCodeModel it cannot auto-complete standard C++. Is there any way to solve this problem? I found the same question in [Qt Creator cannot Auto-Complete Standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62877269/qt-creator-cannot-auto-complete-standard-c). But it didn't provide an effective way. Can anyone help me?